# advice on architecture for new user/entitlement checks in Bixby

Tags: bixby

I am getting ready to add a couple of persistence features to Bixby and want some advice on how to architect it. Specifically, I am going to add

1) check if user is new user
2) if existing user, check entitlements to content packages, each package has a string identifier

These are silent checks, they should be carried out prior to any utterance interaction.

My first thought was to create an action called Initialize with model, action, and code but no view and to call it as a require at the top of each action script.  does that make sense?  are there some good examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't a very stack overflow-friendly question so I plowed ahead on my own. What I wound up doing to begin with is simply adding some code to the default-action.

```
module.exports.function = function (searchTerm, $vivContext) {

  // check if user is already registered

  // create query terms
        bixbyUserId = $vivContext.bixbyUserId
        const checkuserurl = properties.get("config", "baseUrl") + 'example-user-data'
        const checkuserquery = {
          apikey: properties.get("secret", "apiKey"),
          q: "{\"" + properties.get("config", "userIdField") + "\":\"" + bixbyUserId + "\"}"
        }
        const checkuseroptions = {
          format: "json",
          query: checkuserquery,
          cacheTime: 0
        }

  // submit query checking if user is in db

  const checkuserresponse = http.getUrl(checkuserurl, checkuseroptions)

  // if user exists in restdb, accept the userData

          if (checkuserresponse && checkuserresponse.length === 1) {
            var userData = checkuserresponse[0][properties.get("config", "userDataField")]
            userData.$id = checkuserresponse[0]["_id"]
            userData.bixbyuserid = bixbyUserId
            console.log ('user exists and user id is', userData.bixbyuserid)
          }
          else {
    // if user doesn't exist, create new user id in db with UserData    
            var userData = {}
            userData.newuser = true
            const createuserbody = {}
              createuserbody[properties.get("config", "userIdField")] = bixbyUserId
              createuserbody[properties.get("config", "userDataField")] = JSON.stringify(userData)

            const createuserresponse = http.postUrl(checkuserurl, createuserbody, checkuseroptions)

            console.log("user didn't exist in restdb so created one")
          }

  // get AltBrains
```

Needs testing and could benefit from a logic check.